# Interactive message button to copy contents to clipboard

Tags: slack, slack-api

my bot returns some contents and I want to copy that content over to the clipboard. Obviously, the user can select the content and copy. But, from a UI perspective since this is a slack BOT, I was thinking about adding an interactive button - "copy" which when clicked will copy the contents to the clipboard. I know this sounds weird but this was an ask from an exec for whom I am building the app. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you like to get an answer to your problem, you please need to be a lot more specific on what your issues is. Also please add your current source code and what is not working.

Comment: Thanks for responding. my bot returns some contents and I want to copy that content over to the clipboard. Obviously, the user can select the content and copy. But, from a UI perspective since this is a slack BOT, I was thinking about adding an interactive button - "copy" which when clicked will copy the contents to the clipboard. I know this sounds weird but this was an ask from an exec for whom I am building the app. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: To word it differently. How can I call a system command (copy in this case) from an interactive button on slack.

Comment: Thanks for the additional Info. Please add that info to your original question, so that ppl better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Interactive buttons in Slack do not directly support copying content to the user's clipboard. They only do one of two things:

1. Send a request to a Slack app for further processing (see [interactive buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons))
2. Redirect the user to a webpage (see [link buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#attaching_buttons_to_messages))

However, to implement this feature you could redirect to a webpage that implements the copy to clipboard feature via java script ([example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)).

Comment: That is pretty sneaky of Slack developers to keep people using their platform. Lots harder to retype by hand than to get a link to the message itself…